# SwiftUI: Double picker wheels with system behavioral

Tags: swiftui, picker

I want to recreate system picker behavioral with two options in wheels with SwiftUI and faced ton of problem. Some of this I solved but some still unsolved. I have pop-ups with different views inside. One of the view it's a `DatePicker` with `displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute.` And other one is two Pickers inside `HStack`. My question is how to make Pickers make look like in system: without white spacing between?

```
struct MultyPicker: View {
    @State var value = 1
    @State var value2 = 1
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.black.opacity(0.5)
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Header")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(1..<26) { number in
                                Text("\(number)")
                                    .tag("\(number)")
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .compositingGroup()
                        .clipped(antialiased: true)
                        
                        Picker(selection: $value2, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(25..<76) { number in
                                Text("\(number)")
                                    .tag("\(number)")
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                        .compositingGroup()
                        .clipped(antialiased: true)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 34)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                )
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom, 50)
            
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .horizontal])
    }
}

// This extension for correct touching area
    extension UIPickerView {
        open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)
        }
    }
```

Want to achive looks like that with one grey line in selected value

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## iOS 17

One "hack" you could try is bringing the two pickers together so they look like one by:

1. Clipping the rounded corners of the gray selector.
2. Adjusting the positions so they touch each other.

### Example

```
struct CustomPickerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Before")
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Picker(selection: .constant(3), label: Text("Picker")) {
                    Text("1 lb").tag(1)
                    Text("2 lb").tag(2)
                    Text("3 lb").tag(3)
                    Text("4 lb").tag(4)
                    Text("5 lb").tag(5)
                    Text("6 lb").tag(6)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                
                Picker(selection: .constant(3), label: Text("Picker")) {
                    Text("1 oz").tag(1)
                    Text("2 oz").tag(2)
                    Text("3 oz").tag(3)
                    Text("4 oz").tag(4)
                    Text("5 oz").tag(5)
                    Text("6 oz").tag(6)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            }
            .padding()
            
            Text("After")
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Picker(selection: .constant(3), label: Text("Picker")) {
                    Text("1 lb").tag(1)
                    Text("2 lb").tag(2)
                    Text("3 lb").tag(3)
                    Text("4 lb").tag(4)
                    Text("5 lb").tag(5)
                    Text("6 lb").tag(6)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                .clipShape(.rect.offset(x: -16))
                .padding(.trailing, -16)
                
                Picker(selection: .constant(3), label: Text("Picker")) {
                    Text("1 oz").tag(1)
                    Text("2 oz").tag(2)
                    Text("3 oz").tag(3)
                    Text("4 oz").tag(4)
                    Text("5 oz").tag(5)
                    Text("6 oz").tag(6)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                .clipShape(.rect.offset(x: 16))
                .padding(.leading, -16)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .font(.title)
    }
}
```

[image: Before & After]

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  Test2.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by Serdar Onur KARADAĞ on 26.08.2022.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Test2: View {
@State var choice1 = 0
@State var choice2 = 0
       
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.gray.opacity(0.2))
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .frame(width: 350, height: 400)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.white.opacity(1))
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 350)
            VStack {
                Text("HEADER")
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Picker(selection: $choice1, label: Text("C1")) {
                        ForEach(0..<10) { n in
                            Text("\(n)").tag(n)
                       }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0)
                    .clipped()
                    
                    Picker(selection: $choice2, label: Text("C1")) {
                        ForEach(0..<10) { n in
                            Text("\(n)").tag(n)
                       }
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0)
                    .clipped()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct Test2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test2()
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this will be help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI multi-component Picker basically consists of several individual Picker views arranged horizontally. Therefore, we start by creating an ordinary Picker view for our first component. I am using Xcode version 13.4.1(iOS 15.0).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var hourSelect = 0
    @State var minuteSelect = 0
    
    var hours = [Int](0..<24)
    var minutes = [Int](0..<60)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .opacity(0.5)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .preferredColorScheme(.light)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.white.opacity(1))
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 350)
            VStack {
                Text("Header")
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Picker(selection: $hourSelect, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(0..<self.hours.count) { index in
                                Text("\(self.hours[index])").tag(index)
                           }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0)
                        .compositingGroup()
                        .clipped()
                        
                        Picker(selection: $minuteSelect, label: Text("")) {
                            ForEach(0..<self.minutes.count) { index in
                                Text("\(self.minutes[index])").tag(index)
                           }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                        .frame(minWidth: 0)
                        .compositingGroup()
                        .clipped()
                    }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

## Output :

[image]

Comment: What kind of version of Xcode do you using? I'm tried in 13.1 (iOS 15) and it's doesn't give screenshot's behavioral, still white spacing between grey lines...

Comment: I am using Xcode version 13.4.1 (iOS 15.5)

Comment: Please try now to implement this, I have updated the code which is now compatable to every iOS version.

Comment: UI looks perfect with removing `UIPickerView` extension, but in this case touch area of pickers is incorrect and feels like offsets to the left.  Please try to run you code on device and test feedback from pickers, is touch area is ok?

Comment: Ok, I will check this issue you are facing and inform you soon.

Comment: I have checked and get that if we are not using UIPickerView extension if works great and if we use it so we have to give offset to the particular picker view to adjust the position of it. For example :-

Picker(selection: $minute, label: Text("")) {}.offset(x: -15)